# mysql syntax update record based on other record same table

Tags: mysql, sql

How do i make sql syntax on mysql,
when i want to update parent_id based on id on the other record on the same table with the same value on specific column field, example field Code

i tried to make the following

```
update product_class t1
set t1.parent_id = t2.id
WHERE t1.family_code <>'' and t1.class_code = ''
join product_class t2
on 
(t1.segment_code = t2.segment_code)
```

but gives me error

Here is the table structure:
[image: table schema]

Comment: Please show us the *actual* error message, don't just say "I get an error".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct syntax:

```
update product_class t1 join
       product_class t2
       on t1.segment_code = t2.segment_code
    set t1.parent_id = t2.id
    where t1.family_code <> '' and t1.class_code = '';
```

The `join` is part of the `update` clause in MySQL.

NOTE:  the query doesn't look like it would do the right thing.  You are doing a self-join on what looks like a non-unique column, which will generate lots of matches.  An arbitrary matching row would then be used for the `update`.